# Change iostreams in child process

Tags: c++, linux, fork, iostream

Right now, I'm working on a project in which I need to start a child process to execute a new program in Linux using C++, and I need to redirect standard input and output (as in C++, they are `cin` and `cout`) to a file. This means that in the child process, the standard input and output are both files. The child process will read input from a file (whose name would be `input.txt`), and output to a file (whose name would be `output.txt`).

By using `cin.rdbuf()` and `cout.rdbuf()`, I can actually redirect `cin` and `cout` in the parent process. But it doesn't work when the child process starts an `execl()` command. It seems that after the child process executes the `execl()` command, the standard input and output return to normal.

Can anyone can help me with this problem? I've been confused for the past few days and can't find a way out.

Code is as follows:

//main.cpp

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/ptrace.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include<string>
#include"executor.cpp"
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
executor ex;
ex.set_path("/home/test");
ex.run_program();
}
```

//executor.cpp

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/ptrace.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
class executor{
public:
void run_program()
{
    char p[50];
    strcpy(p,path.c_str());
    cpid = fork();
    if(cpid == 0)
    {
                    ifstream file("/home/openjudge/data.txt");
            if(!file) cout<<"file open failed\n";
            streambuf* x = cin.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,0,NULL,NULL);
        execl(p,"test","NULL);
        cin.rdbuf(x);
        cout<<"execute failed!\n";
    }
    else if(cpid > 0)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        cout<<"i'm a father\n";
    }
}
void set_path(string p)
{
    path = p;
}
private:
int cpid;
string path;
};
```

P.S. `/home/test` is a simple program which reads from `cin` and outputs to `cout`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the file descriptors `0` (standard input) and `1` (standard output) after `fork()` your child:

```
switch (fork()) {
case 0: {
    close(0);
    if (open(name, O_RDONLY) < 0) {
        deal_with_error();
    }
    ...
```

You might want to open the files directed to in the parent process. Having the files readily open probably makes error handling easier. In this case you'd use `dup2()` to associate the correct file descriptor with the file.

Comment: Thank a lot!  dup2() did work! and i also found that freopen() can redirect standard input and output too.  But, i still have a question. These functions ( dup2() and freopen()) are both in C library, is there any way to do this in C++ ?